# how to sync data between android app and php server?

Tags: php, android, database, synchronization

I am trying to sync data between android application and php server.

In my application I use json webservices to get data from php server.

Now whenever there is new fields added to php server database then my app should reflect it immediately.

Its kind of background services which we look everytime for the new data to php server database.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 5):

If you need this immediately, you should consider using [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).

This sentence is on the GCM's front page:

> Send data from your server to users' Android-powered devices. This could be a lightweight message telling your app there is new data to be fetched from the server

What you would need to do is to make your backend notify GCM about new data (via GCM's web service). Then, it's GCM's responsibility to deliver this message to your app. It'll even launch app when it's not running.

As for specific solution, you have two possibilities: either backend will only "ping" app via GCM, and app will fetch data by itself, or, if the update is small, backend could send it to your app directly in the GCM message.

Comment: you are right at your place but I have list which show image,title and description for customers(says), if any new customer's information is added to the php database then my app should add that information as the first row of my list. I think GCM is unable to send images or data with its keys to identify uniquely

Comment: So you would only send new customer's ID via GCM, and app will fetch all the necessary data. Yes, you can send your arbitrary data over GCM (up to 4kb) - it's contained in `data` parameter described as: "A JSON object whose fields represents the key-value pairs of the message's payload data. If present, the payload data it will be included in the Intent as application data, with the key being the extra's name. For instance, "data":{"score":"3x1"} would result in an intent extra named score whose value is the string 3x1." [source](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html)

Comment: Alternatively you could send all data except for big ones (images) - this way your app would receive them faster, show it to the user, and in the background download only images.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at SyncAdapter class especially designed for this purpose.
http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html